# How can i debug maven test in VSCode

Tags: spring-boot, maven, visual-studio-code

I have a spring boot app doing some integration test.

I start the mvn test task with a parameter: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9000

In a normal spring boot app i would connect once the server is up and running but the tests are so fast that i cant connect to the port from vscode.

Is there a way to debug tests?

Answer (score 0):

If you run the integration test through maven, there is a good chance the server will be taken down before you get a chance to connect to it.

Instead, run the integration test directly from your IDE. This is more reliable approach ;)

I use a different IDE to vscode (I use IntelliJ) and there I can right click on the Integration test in the code and run it from there. To pause the test, I simply set a breakpoint.

Comment: I know that Intellij can do that fromt he IDE. But thats not the point.

Comment: So figure out how to do it in your idea. And btw, why are you using vscode? this is java, not c sharp...