Debugging Java unit tests in VSCode
I'm trying to debug a class when the JUnit test is run, however, my configuration seems to be incorrect:
tasks.json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Maven: compile",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "mvn",
      "args": ["compile"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "problemMatcher": ["$maven"],
      "detail": "Compile the project using Maven"
    },
    {
      "label": "Maven: test",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "mvn",
      "args": ["test"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "test",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "problemMatcher": ["$maven"],
      "dependsOn": "Maven: compile",
      "detail": "Run all tests using Maven"
    },
    {
      "label": "Maven: test XodusDatabaseTest",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "mvn",
      "args": ["compile", "test", "-Dtest=XodusDatabaseTest"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "test",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "problemMatcher": ["$maven"],
      "detail": "Run XodusDatabaseTest using Maven"
    },
    {
      "label": "Maven: debug XodusDatabaseTest",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "mvn",
      "args": [
        "compile", 
        "test",
        "-Dtest=XodusDatabaseTest",
        "-Dmaven.surefire.debug"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": ["$maven"],
      "detail": "Debug XodusDatabaseTest using Maven"
    }
  ]
}


launch.json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "java",
      "name": "Debug Test XodusDatabaseTest",
      "request": "launch",
      "mainClass": "",
      "preLaunchTask": "Maven: debug XodusDatabaseTest",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "vmArgs": "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "debugServer": 5005 
    }
  ]
}

Running "Debug Test..." is stuck waiting for the debugger:
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005

I expect it to proceed with the unit tests and stop at any breakpoint set in VScode.

duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75670493/how-can-i-debug-maven-test-in-vscode

you can try adding "mainClass": "your main class name" to the launch.json file. Besides, you can use win+R to enter cmd, and then input netstat -ano | findstr 5005 with the command。 Check whether the port is occupied. If it is occupied, you can open explorer to see if the occupied process is critical. Close and try again. You can check out the document for Java debugging and testing.
